# Can't format the timezone of the date returned by DateTimeInlineRow

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

```
let rowEndTime = form.rowByTag("End Time")?.baseValue
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        let stringEnd = formatter.stringFromDate((rowEndTime as? NSDate)!)

        print(stringEnd)
```

I am trying to convert the date returned by the row to the local timezone, and then into a string. stringFromDate is always returning nil and I cannot seem to get the timezone to stick. Any ideas how I am meant to do this?

Comment: Setting the `locale` of `NSDateFormatter` to the current locale is redundant, because the current locale is the default but you need to specify a date format.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm still getting the wrong date.

Comment: Probably you're getting the right date, but if you print it out, it displays the date in time in UTC and your time zone is most likely not UTC. Consider that `locale` != `time zone`.

Comment: Right. How can I set the timezone to the local timezone?

Comment: formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
I tried this and it still didn't work

Comment: The date formatter considers the local time zone by default (unlike the `print` command). If you really need the UTC representation you have to set the time zone to UTC

Answer (score 0):

try do to as follow-

```
let rowEndTime = form.rowByTag("End Time")?.baseValue
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM y"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en-US")//or NSLocale.currentLocale()
let stringEnd = formatter.stringFromDate((rowEndTime as? NSDate)!)
```